# Can I return two types of data with composer

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I would like to ask if I can return two types of data into view with coposer. currently I only return two variables as below:

```
$view->with(['evens' => $evens, 'likeArr' => $likeArr ]);
```

But now I would like to add up another value but return it as json. Is there anyway I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Can achieve like this

```
$view->with(['evens' => $evens, 'likeArr' => $likeArr ,'json_data'=>json_encode($data)]);
```

For reference: [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Well when you return a variable to your views it can be an `array`, `string`, `integer`, and so on.. so I don't think there will be a problem returning a `json` variable. Just [encode it](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) an return it:

```php
$variable = json_encode($data);
$view->with(['evens' => $evens, 'someJsonVariable' => $variable ]);
```

In case you can't do it, or just want to do it directly in your view you could do this in a Blade file:

```php
{{ $newVar = json_encode($variable) }}
```